# How To Animate Skeletal Interactions (Hugging, Handshakes etc.)

Tags: animation, unreal-4, skeletal-animation, 3dsmax

I am fairly new to animating and IK systems, but I've got the basics down to some extend. Now I am looking into how to go about skeletal actor animation interactions such as handshakes, fighting, horse riding, hugging or sex animations and such, to be used in unreal engine 4. I would like someone to point me into the right direction on how to go about this.

As I am new to this, if the question is too broad or vague please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: Character A is touching with the hand on character B's Head.
In content, you need to define **the offset** to your attachment. So you would create a bone under Character's A's hand, and then constrain it to the Head of character B.

In the engine, you then IK the hand from character A to the Head of character B, but you add the (inverted) offset that is stored (and animated) with your offset bone. That way it is attached but animated.

This is a general answer - the exact clicks/code-pieces you need to do in Unreal Engine 4 I can't answer.

Comment: That was pretty helpful, I understand the gist of your answer.